# we are using postman and swagger for JWT authorization to authorize token ... is it possible in drf UI for authorization of JWT token?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We are using postman and swagger for authenticating and authorizing the JWT authentication we are logging in and we are getting both access token and refresh token and we are placing this access token in swagger/postman as bearer token and authorizing..
Is it possible in DRF UI for authorizing token and accessing the API's

Expecting JWT Authorizing and accessing all the API's in DRF UI instead of swagger and Postman